# template node local library import

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have to setup a, most of the time, offline installation of Node-RED and need to use the "Chart.js" Library in a template node. Currently my working approach is to copy the Chart.js dictory to node-red-dashboard/dist/js and import it with `<script src= "js/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>`. But when I want to update the dashboard I need to copy everything again. So it would be nice to have a permanent Solution for this.

I tryed two other approaches until now. For both I installed Chart.js to the .node-red dictory. 
First I tryed it like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var ChartJs = require('Chart.js');
var chart = new ChartJs(canvas, {... }
```

in a script tag (... stands for the working chart code that is not edited), but it didn't work aswell as to put 
`functionGlobalContext: {chartjs:require('Chart.js')}` into settings.js and change `require('Chart.js')` to `global.get('chartjs')`

Does anyone here has an Idea to solve this properly? Unfortunately the node throws no Error to the console so I don't get an idea whats wrong here.

Thanks in advance for every hint or solution,

manni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want to use any 3rd party charting library in my node-red dashboard, I put 2 `ui_template` nodes into my flow:

1. under "Template Type" select the "Added to site `<head>` section" and add the link to the library's url:

   ```
   <script src="url/to/library.js"></script>
   ```

   *(which in your offline case would be a local url)*
2. use the library's exported objects directly within the template, without using `require`, such as:

   ```
   <div id="myChart"></div>

   <script>
       var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
       var chart = new ChartJs(canvas, { ... }
   </script>
   ```

The trick is to have your local node-red instance serve the ChartJS library through a local url. For that, first add this require **path** line to the **settings.js** file, before the exports section:

```
// The `https` setting requires the `fs` module. Uncomment the following
// to make it available:
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require ("path");
```

then, uncomment the httpStatic section below that, within the exports:

```
// When httpAdminRoot is used to move the UI to a different root path, the
// following property can be used to identify a directory of static content
// that should be served at http://localhost:1880/.
httpStatic: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
```

*(you can use any directory name, in place of `public`)* The `__dirname` references the node-red server's working directory, usually `.node-red` under your home directory.

Create this new *public* directory, copy the ChartJS files under it, and restart node-red. At startup, you should see a line in the console log showing the path to your new static file location:

```
5 Feb 12:12:23 - [info] Settings file  : C:\NODE\node_red_ui\settings.js
5 Feb 12:12:23 - [info] HTTP Static    : C:\NODE\node_red_ui\public
5 Feb 12:12:23 - [info] User directory : C:\NODE\node_red_ui
```

Now you can serve the local file `public\scripts\abc.js` using the local url 
`http://localhost:1880/scripts/abc.js`
This way, npm updates to the dashboard code will not overwrite your static files.

Comment: I'm sorry to reopen this. But I connected to the dashboard remotely now and had to notice, that the graphics aren't showing from any networked computer.
Edit: Okay, I had to us my network IP/Address not local host. Is there an option to link to the network ip dynamicaly if I use the code on different computers?

Comment: That's more of a Unix sys admin question, but the short answer is "Yes" -- it's called DNS, the standard service for mapping IP addresses to host names. By default, the name `localhost` is the only "host name" known to each system, and is mapped to its own address.